# Android how to create multiple instances of pending intent with different request codes using single BroadCast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

#this method is used trigger the pending intents using alarm manager with different id's#i just want create pending intent for each id after 30 sec i want cancel the trigger id#

**int bulletin id =1,2,3,4,5,6,7(the id's will get dynamically from api not hardcoded so it can be 1 to 100);**`

```
public void setOk(Context context, int okId) {
        triggerAlarm(context ,okId);
    }
private void triggerAlarm(Context context, int bulletinId) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmManager != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, BulletinReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("bulletinId", bulletinId);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, bulletinId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            //set time to next 30 sec
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 30);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
            LogUtils.d(TAG, "triggerAlarm: ");
        }
    }
```

BulletinReceiver:

```
public class BulletinReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BulletinReceiver";
    int bulletinID;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LogUtils.d(TAG, "onReceive: ");
        bulletinID = intent.getIntExtra("bulletinId",0);
        Log.d("Sathish", "onreciver: bulletinId: " + bulletinID);
        ArrayList<Integer> okBulletinIdList = SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(context).geOkBulletinIdList();
        if(okBulletinIdList.size()>0){
            okBulletinIdList.remove((Integer) bulletinID);

        }
        SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(context).setOkBulletinIdList(okBulletinIdList);
        BulletinMessageUtils.getInstance().setBulletinTimerFlag(context, bulletinID);
        Log.d("Sathish", "onreciver canceld: bulletinId: " +  SharedPreferenceUtils.getInstance(context).geOkBulletinIdList().toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: You have the code. What is your problem?

Comment: as i mentioned above how to create pending intent for each "ID" using single broadcast receiver and cancel the  the intent of particular id after 30 sec

Comment: Sorry, still don't understand your problem. You are already creating a `PendingIntent`. And setting an alarm with it that will trigger in 30 seconds. What else do you want to do with this `PendingIntent`?

Comment: For example: i have a different request code (0,1,2,3,4) and i want to create PendingIntent for each request code(in this case bulletinID in my code) with single broadcast receiver and cancel the pendingIntent based on request code.

Comment: You already said that. It makes no sense. You already posted code that creates a `PendingIntent` with a differnt request code. Fine. Now, what do you want to do with that `PendingIntent`? It isn't clear what you want to do